# Google channel api for c/c++ client

Tags: c++, google-app-engine, channel-api

Is there a c/c++ client for google channel api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The only official client is witten in Javascript.

Answer (score 4):

Well, you could probably write your own client, since my understanding is that it's "just" HTTP and JSON.

There's an outstanding [feature request](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4206) that Google is resolutely ignoring to get alternative client APIs.

Answer (score 0):

You can write an own client using [libCURL](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) for your HTTP requests and [json-cpp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jsoncpp/) to read/write JSON with C++.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps.  Google has recently announced new C++ API for almost all their services:

https://google-api-client-libraries.appspot.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/compute/v1beta15/cpp/latest/